# I want to place these 3 buttons in a circle under the timer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, html5-canvas

I want to place these 3 buttons in a circle under the timer. Please see images for reference. I'm trying to put these 3 buttons inside the circle but it always crashes my layout. I have attached my code and css- please check it

```css
.circle {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    line-height: 320px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 10px solid #666;
    border-style: double;
}

.circleContent {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 40px;
    width: 60px;
}

.circleContent-span {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <div>
            <h1 class="title">Stop Watch</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="circle mt-5">
            <div>
                <h1 id="hour" class="circleContent">00</h1><span class="circleContent-span">:</span>
                <h1 id="min" class="circleContent">00</h1><span class="circleContent-span">:</span>
                <h1 id="sec" class="circleContent">00</h1><span class="circleContent-span">:</span>
                <h1 id="msec" class="circleContent">00</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <button onclick="start()">Start</button>
            <button onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
            <button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
```

```
    .circle {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    line-height: 320px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 10px solid #666;
    border-style: double;
}

.circleContent {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 40px;
    width: 60px;
}

.circleContent-span {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 40px;
}

       
    
Buttons

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Circle
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
    
    


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5Qve.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaIH2.png
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please review [ask] and provide a [mcve] when asking a question. You haven't provided any css-code to accompany your html. This is not a free coding service

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will help

```
 <div class="container mt-5 h-position-relative">
        <div>
            <h1 class="title">Stop Watch</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="circle mt-5">
            <div>
                <h1 id="hour" class="circleContent">00</h1><span class="circleContent-span">:</span>
                <h1 id="min" class="circleContent">00</h1><span class="circleContent-span">:</span>
                <h1 id="sec" class="circleContent">00</h1><span class="circleContent-span">:</span>
                <h1 id="msec" class="circleContent">00</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="h-position-absolute h-tl">
            <button onclick="start()">Start</button>
            <button onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
            <button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.h-position-relative{
position:relative;
}

.h-position-absolute{
position:absolute;

}

.h-tl{
top:smth;
left:smth;
}
```

Comment: It should work bro :) 
I think you are making some mistake, Can you please update your code on question with changes so that I can help.

Comment: Check my updated code here: https://jsfiddle.net/obh0mru4/1/

Comment: whats your screen resolution?

Comment: `.h-tl {
   top:350px;
    left:220px;
}`

Comment: delete that `.h-t1 { top:smth; left:smth; }` on css and replace it with above code

Answer (score 0):

**If you want something like this**
[image: If you want something like this]
**Than this will help:**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    body {
      background-color: lightblue;
    }
    
    .circle {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 350px;
        height: 350px;
        line-height: 320px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        text-align: center;
        border: 10px solid #666;
        border-style: double;
    }
    
    .circleContent {
        display: inline-block;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 40px;
        width: 60px;
    }
    
    .circleContent-span {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    .h-position-relative{
    position:relative;
    }
    
    .h-position-absolute{
    position:absolute;
    
    }
    
    .h-tl{
    top:350px;
    left:250px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
     <div class="container mt-5 h-position-relative">
            <div>
                <h1 class="title">Stop Watch</h1>
            </div>
    
            <div class="circle mt-5">
                <div>
                    <h1 id="hour" class="circleContent">00</h1><span class="circleContent-span">:</span>
                    <h1 id="min" class="circleContent">00</h1><span class="circleContent-span">:</span>
                    <h1 id="sec" class="circleContent">00</h1><span class="circleContent-span">:</span>
                    <h1 id="msec" class="circleContent">00</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="h-position-absolute h-tl">
                <button onclick="start()">Start</button>
                <button onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
                <button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I'm getting this result. The buttons are not in the circle:

see this link: https://ibb.co/vdY7hgN

Comment: Check my updated code here: jsfiddle.net/obh0mru4/1

Comment: inspect and keep increase the left value until you are done, Than it will work